# Creating object of view class in ViewModel class in mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on mvvm in c# wpf, I have a little understanding of mvvm.
I am creating an object of my View class in My ViewMode classl.so is it violating mvvm pattern? and how ? it would be great if some one explains this in detail..

Comment: "so is it violating mvvm pattern?" Yes it is. The view model shouldn't know the view.

Comment: thanx for the comment but can u explain why ? I am new to mvvm

Comment: How about just searching the web? There are plenty of online resources.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the MVVM pattern is to maintain separation of the View (the display that presents controls to the user) from the Model (data, the business logic, data-access) and the ViewModel (the glue between the model and the view). The VM should not have to worry about UI (i.e. View) concerns, so creating and using a view within a viewmodel is violating that MVVM pattern.

A View is nearly always made up of UI elements, such as buttons or textblocks. A Viewmodel should be concerned with things like properties, such as a `UserName`, or a `StartDate`, or a `WarningState`. These VM properties are then bound (with `DataBinding`) to properties on UI elements within a view ... so the view has a dependency on the VM **but not the other way around**. Where the VM gets the data from to populate those properties in the first place is the model, or for data-entry maybe they'll all be blank to begin with and the application relies on the user entering data in the view.

You might want to bind the WarningState to a TextBox, for example, but equally you could bind it to a ComboBox. Or you could use a converter and bind it to the foreground colour of a rectangle, or the background colour of a UI element that is used for something else entirely different.

The point is that these are things the VM doesn't need to worry about: all it cares about is presenting data/state. It is up to the view how it deals with that information (or doesn't deal with it). In this way you could completely replace the view with a different version, and not have to change *anything* in your VM ... you have successfully separated your display from your logic.

Comment: The point of MVVM is testability... that is why you want to separate your view from the view model. Once that has been done you can unit test your view model without needing to test the view. It's difficult to take an explanation of MVVM seriously when it fails to mention unit testing.

Comment: That is definitely **one** point of MVVM yes. I tried to create a simple explanation, because as clemens pointed out there are plenty of online resources to direct the OP's learning. My answer wasn't complete, but I don't think that means the points I made are 'difficult to take seriously'. If you can swap out one view and completely replace it with a vastly different view, and not have to change anything about your model or VM then you can be pretty happy you've successfully separated your concerns. Try doing that in Winforms (without using MMVM).